What is a rigorous refutation for subjective extrapolations of scientific research?
Imagine you are confronted with the choice to use marijuana or not, and you wonder, “what might the longterm effects be, good or bad?”
If you look at the Wikipedia page for ‘marijuana’, you might find a summary there of what our culture apparently finds some of the essential, definitive, and most relevant information about marijuana. One sub-topic in that survey may include the ‘overall effects’ of using cannabis on things like physical health and social “outcomes”.
One thing that the current Wikipedia page says is that use of marijuana in adolescence is linked with “decreased mental ability” later in life.
It is really common for people to cite scientific research like “phenomenon X has correlation Y” (like, “taking this substance leads to a certain good/bad effect”).
(There is even a cool article I want to read about this called “Why most published research is false.”)
Furthermore, “scientific research” is really just supposed to be, “ways of generating sound knowledge”. As in, there are surely other ways to “know” something, than if a scientific study has been published on it.
The idea is, it is not an adequate methodology of judgment to only think in terms of what scientific research has currently been published. We can imagine tomorrow there is always room for a hypothetical study that reveals something we do not currently know. Just to prove a point, it could be something extremely random like “people who smoke marijuana in childhood are better at basketball”.
So, what kind of a methodology allows us to infer that our knowledge is comprehensive?
This applies to many scientific scenarios.
Is there something deeply wrong with forming judgments based on known correlations, while being unable to prove that there are no unknown correlations waiting to be discovered?
Could such an argument be formulated so systematically that it could become an integral part of scientific practice, and scientific communication with the public: that a study identifying a correlation is not a valid basis for extrapolating many of the judgments a human might commonly extrapolate?
It is as if we need a “scientific method” that is not based on the idea of “finding correlations”, but something like “comprehensive knowledge”.

I love the core philosophical dilemma present in your question but I think you should ask it in a strictly philosophical manner, instead of discussing the greens specifically, discuss the dilemma  you are facing with  the philosophy of present correlations and future correlations to come (temporal correlations/knowledge). Based on your feedback, you can then apply the arguments to specific scenarios of one's life wisely.

I have voted to close this question as off-topic because although parts of it pertaining to the general question of experimentation and data analysis are philosophy, the core question is about a specific empirical claim.

Wikipedia is not a scientific source, nor in most cases a legitimate source at all.  With the Wiki process it is easy to introduce and maintain bias on Wiki pages, and the stability of biased pages over time has been verified.  If your "scientific research" starts and ends with Wiki, no wonder you do not trust science.  Wiki is very often useful to get an intro to a subject that you are not already familiar with, to then search for better references with useful terms. But you already HAVE an into to marijuana, so you are misusing Wiki.


It is really common for people to cite scientific research like “phenomenon X has correlation Y” (like, “taking this substance leads to a certain good/bad effect”).

It is a well-known fallacy to conclude from "phenomenon X has correlation Y" that phenomenon X leads to a certain effect.

what kind of a methodology allows us to infer that our knowledge is comprehensive?

No methodology allows us to infer that our knowledge is comprehensive, and no scientist that I am aware of makes this claim.

Is there something deeply wrong with forming judgments based on known correlations, while being unable to prove that there are no unknown correlations waiting to be discovered?

No. The best we can do is build theories based on correlations that we have observed, along with interventions/experiments to attept to discern causation.

+! Great answer. Although I must say for this question, "Is there something deeply wrong with forming judgments based on known correlations, while being unable to prove that there are no unknown correlations waiting to be discovered?" The answer should be it depends, not "No" because if the correlation is weak or pretty much inexistent but one does so because of confirmation bias or some weird dissonance then I think it is wrong, personal take away.
